# How do I print the entire column-sequence in a text file if a matching row-sequence is found?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a text file containing 3 rows: The first row is a start time stamp. 2nd is an end time stamp.
3rd row is a sequence of characters.

If I pass a sequence of characters to my script it should search for the character sequence in the 3rd row and return the entire column where it found it, if it was successful.

I've tried using awk, by transposing the file, but I'm not able to get it right

```
0.01 0.2 0.3
0.02 0.25 0.4
a_B    b_I     b_E
```

If pattern to find is 'a_B b_I' then expected output is:

```
0.01 0.2 
0.02 0.25
a_B b_I
```

Comment: Not always no, They are phone sequences

Comment: I've updated the pattern to find. I already wrote a script that will append the '_B' and '_I' to the characters.

Comment: what are your matching rules that allow you to match 'a_B<space>b_I' with what appears to be 'a_B<multiple_spaces>b_I' or 'a_B<tab>b_I'?

Comment: `awk 'NR>2{for(i in c)s=(s?s FS $i:$i);print s;s=!s}NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)v[$i]++}NR==2{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)for(q in v)if($i~q)c[i]++}' - <(tail -1 file) file <<< 'a_B b_I'`